# Which tool to intercept HTTP(S) requests and provide custom content

Tags: http, http-proxy

I use Selenium webdriver (Firefox) to test a web application. Tests take a long time and I want to reduce this time. The web application make a lot of useless requests (javascript and images) in the context of tests. I know that the behaviour of the application is correct for tests if small images and empty javascript is returned.

What mean can I use to intercept Firefox requests and return content from static files for a given set of patterns of URLs ?

Neither Fiddler or Burp seem to offer this functionnality.

It seems to be complicated with Squid, I need to be able to change configuration quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The browser is already doing it. It's called caching. If you really want to reduce the time of your tests, then you could use a static profile and use the same session for different tests.

Comment: I want to intercept requests which return dynamically generated javascript which will take a long time to process in the browser and will generate some other requests. I want to return empty javascripts for theses requests I have identified.

Answer (score 0):

Finaly I used SQUID to do this and this wasn't so complicated.